# display plot legend in hovertool in Bokeh- I get "???" when I use the "$name" keyword in tooltips

Tags: tooltip, bokeh

Is there an easy way to display the legend associated with a line plot in hovertool. I tried
TOOLTIPS = [
("index", "$index"),
("(x,y)", "($x, $y)"),
("desc", '$name'),
]
but hovetool shows "desc:???" instead of the name of the plot

Comment: `$name` displays the value of the `name` property of the glyph that is being hovered over (that's all it ever does). Did you configure a `name` for the glyph?

Comment: Thank you @bigreddot. I confused `legend_label` property with `name` property. Passing `name` parameter in addition to `legend_label` works shows the proper name now in hovertool . For my example , they are the same.